# Beautifulsoup contents to string raises UnicodeEncodeError

Tags: python, utf-8, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to get string from BeautifulSoup tag contents. The problem is that it raises UnicodeDecodeError:

```
    text = "".join(str(item).decode('unicode') for item in contents)
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\u0160' in position 0: ordinal not in range(128)
```

Here is my code:

```
contents = title.find_next_sibling('div','textNahlad').contents
text = ", ".join(str(item) for item in contents)
```

I tried to encode it to utf-8 but no success, I can't find out where I'm wrong.

The problem is that, unfortunately, `item.encode('utf-8')` / or decode does not work on this kind of objects. 
`item.text.encode` does not work neither because there are no text attribute for this objects.

Could you give me an advice? Thanks

EDIT:

```
for content in contents:
     text += content.string does not work
```

Comment: Please show us the *full* traceback, including the traceback you get for encoding to UTF-8 if that is different.

Comment: In any case, calling `str()` on a Unicode object (like BeautifulSoup `NavigableText` elements) will trigger encoding to ASCII, and that clearly fails for your content. You should never use `str()` but instead explicitly encode to your desired encoding.